# Opt out of ALL "Customer Experience Improvement Programs" (CEIPs)

Tags: windows, privacy

Many Microsoft programs (eg. Office 2007, SQL Server 2008, Visual Studio 2010) ask me if I want to participate in a "Customer Experience Improvement Program". I don't. I really don't. Never. Ever.

I don't really mind them asking **once**, but the problem is that each program asks me separately, which is an unnecessary annoyance. (Some other vendors do this, too, like JetBrains.) Is there an easy way to opt out of **all** these programs, once and for all (at least the Microsoft ones)? Perhaps a little utility that just configures the appropriate settings for any program that might ask this question - before it actually asks?

Comment: i add the same features to the software that i write. Record what features you access, how own, how (e.g. click, keyboard, shortcut), how slow certain operations are. Data is anonymous and sent back home so i can figure out what people use, and what needs to be fixed. Microsoft applications all choose to give it the same name, but it really is per-application. Each application will, through convention, have a spot where you can turn it off. But please don't; it really does help make the products better.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but those are written into each application. They are not done at a Windows level so you can't.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected as much, but was hoping there was a program that turned many (all?) of them off. Maybe I'll try to write one when I have some spare time.